# Merge two multi dimensional object with it's key in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have the below type of 2 objects, with a unique id as a key, now I want to merge these 2 objects as per the key.

**Object 1**

```
var object1 = {
  511:{
    name:'bed',
    color:'blue'
  },
  512:{
    name:'bed',
    color:'blue'
  }
};
```

**Object 2**

```
var object2 = {
  511:{
    price:550000,
    mileage:23.5
  },

  512:{
    price:1550000,
    mileage:12.5
  }
};
```

**Expected output**

```
var result = {
  511:{
    name:'bed',
    color:'blue',
    price:550000,
    mileage:23.5
  },
  512:{
    name:'bed',
    color:'blue',
    price:1550000,
    mileage:12.5
  }
};
```

Comment: what does not work? please add your code.

Comment: What happens if the keys in both objects do not exactly overlap?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
var object1 = {
  511: {
    name: 'bed',
    color: 'blue'
  },
  512: {
    name: 'bed',
    color: 'blue'
  }
};

var object2 = {
  511: {
    price: 550000,
    mileage: 23.5
  },
  512: {
    price: 1550000,
    mileage: 12.5
  }
};

var result = {}

for (let key in object1) {
  result[key] = { ...object1[key],
    ...object2[key]
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: why should it? what about nested properties?

Comment: @NinaScholz Ya it does not work for that, but the op never asked for it. If the structure of the objects is fixed then the solution above should work.